# One cell on the same row affects another cell on the table component wen using antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

This is a question, How to implement the feature: One cell on the same row affects another cell.
For Example:
The cell 1 inputted 100, The second cell must less than 100, It means the second cell value must less than the first cell.

How can I implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

My experience:
All the data store into redux(for example), then check the different cell  base on redux data